# chrome downloaded blocked files location

Tags: google-chrome

I downloaded a file using chrome it downloaded it correctly then chrome blocked it. I don't see it in my downloads folder. But while downloading I could see the partial file in the downloads folder. My question is what is the location of chrome files which are blocked or quarantined? i.e. where they are kept. While downloading is taking place they seem to be in the downloads folder but after chrome passes its judgement it moves it somewhere else.

Comment: They get deleted.

Comment: Blocked for a good reason.